# Wireless Repeaters all Connecting to the Main Router Instead of Closest AP

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, repeater

I have 3 Buffalo WZR-HP-AG300H Routers running DD-WRT firmware to extend a wireless network on a job site.

Router 1 has the device I need access to plugged into one of the ports physical ports and routers 2 and 3 are meant to extend the wireless signal to another part of the building for programming on a laptop.  Router 1 is set up as WDS AP for Wireless mode and 2/3 are set to WDS Station.  When testing in my office, Router 1 is the start of the network, Router 2 is the next furthest away, and Router 3 is the furthest away.  I am going for maximum distance as apposed to blanket coverage (1 ------ > 2 ------ > 3).

Looking under the status section of the Web Interface, it seems that both Router 2 and 3 are connected to Router 1 and not in a chain like I had imagined. I would like to connect 2 to 1, and 3 to 2 and have them do it automatically as I plug them in.  For example if I had 4 or 5 routers, each would find the nearest AP and then communicate to Router 1 that way.

I had the Gateway and Local DNS on 2 and 3 set to the IP of Router 1 and the signal strength showed that both were directly connected to router 1 (3 was weaker than 2).  I then set the subnet and GW of Router 3 to that of 2 and nothing seemed to change signal wise, although it did show up in the Active Clients list of Router 2.

Thanks for your time.

Edit:  I forgot to mention that I am using a Virtual Interface for access to the network while the Wireless Physical Interface is bridging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If router 1 is AP and 2 and 3 are station, how is 3 supposed to get a signal from 2 - it's not an AP?

You need to create 2 profiles on router 2, so it acts as a station to router 1 and an AP to router 3. My WRT experience is limited so I am not sure if you have that option though. Netgear WNDAP360 I know for fact can bridge the way you want and allow client connections on the same frequency as well, so they might be worth looking at if you have spare cash on the job?

As a footnote, you are right that 5GHz does have a shorter range. It also lacks the penetrative ability of 2.4GHz so signals are hampered more by walls, floors, doors etc

Comment: I set up a second virtual interface on #2 and had #3 set as a WDS Station to that.  Now its 1, 2, 3 in that order.  Unfortunately I can't seem to have #3 choose whichever signal is closest but, this has answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your router seems supported by OpenWRT. I would use OpenWRT, since at the moment is more powerful and in my humble opinion the new bootstrap-based interface is the easiest and most beautiful of all WRT software out there, commercial or not.

Since your router seems to support concurrent dual band (please confirm this), I would setup the 5 ghz band as a backbone, so you can use 40 mhz channels, and connect the repeater to a 5 ghz network.

The 2.4 ghz network would be free on the main ap and repeaters to be used by the clients.

By setting up a separate 5 ghz network, you can squeeze the most out of your hardware, in term of available bandwidth, latency, reliability and QoS. If you use WDS your network is forced to go at the speed of the maximum common denominator, which is usually very low.

Comment: It is dual band.  I thought that the 5 ghz network, while faster, had considerably shorter range than 2.4. I forgot to mention that I am using a virtual interface to connect to the network while the main interface is bridging.

Comment: the openwrt sports a much newer kernel (several years newer) compared to ddwrt, which will dramatically improve your performance. This setup will allow you to choose who picks what.